# How to check if a QObject is a descendant of a QObject?

Tags: qt, qt5

```
QObject* a;
QObject* b;

//a and b are created somewhere else

bool existed = b.contains(a);//check if b contains a recursively
```

I'm wondering if there exists any API for this?

Comment: Do you know what the type of `a` is? If so you would use [`findChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild)

Comment: `findChild` searches by name and `a` doesn't have a name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`QObject::findChildren`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) without any arguments for this purpose:

Something like this:

```
bool exists = b->findChildren<QObject*>().contains(a);
```

Note that I think that the fact you need this might imply a design fault and you should rethink what you're trying to accomplish in such a way that this hack isn't necessary. It may well be this cannot be done, but don't just keep doing this kind of thing, as it's quite ugly and can become painfully slow if you're relying on this from the start.

Comment: I'm actually trying to find out if the focused window is the window embeded via `QWidget::createWindowContainer`. But `QGuiApplication::focusWindow()` seems never return the container widget/window. So I'm trying to find the embeded window in `QGuiApplication::focusWindow()`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than asking "is 'a' a descendant of 'b'?" try turning it round and asking "is 'b' an ancestor of 'a'?".  Then just use repeated calls to [`QObject::parent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#parent).  Something like (untested)...

```
bool is_ancestor_of (const QObject *descendant, const QObject *ancestor)
{
    if (!ancestor)
        return false;
    while (descendant) {
        if (descendant == ancestor)
            return true;
        descendant = descendant->parent();
    }
    return false;
}
```